# SwiftUI - DispatchQueue.main.async in HealthKit

Tags: swiftui, healthkit

I want to load the following GUI in SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var test = Test()
    @ObservedObject var healthStore = HealthStore()
    
    
    func callUpdate() {
        
        print(test.value)
        print(healthStore.systolicValue)
        print(healthStore.diastolicValue)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Platzhalter")
            .padding()
            .onAppear(perform: {
            healthStore.setUpHealthStore()
                callUpdate()
            })
        
        Button("Test"){
            callUpdate()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The variables healthStore.systolicValue and healthStore.diastolicValue are called via the function callUpdate(). On the first call both variables are nil. Only when I call the function via the Test button, the correct value is output in the console.

The variables healthStore.systolicValue and healthStore.diastolicValue are calculated in the class HealthStore:

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit

class HealthStore: ObservableObject {

    var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
    var query: HKStatisticsQuery?
    
    public var systolicValue: HKQuantity?
    public var diastolicValue: HKQuantity?

    init() {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        }
    }

    func setUpHealthStore() {
        let typesToRead: Set = [
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureSystolic)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureDiastolic)!
        ]

        healthStore?.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: typesToRead, completion: { success, error in
            if success {
                print("requestAuthrization")
                self.calculateBloodPressureSystolic()
                self.calculateBloodPressureDiastolic()
            }
        })

    }

    func calculateBloodPressureSystolic() {
        guard let bloodPressureSystolic = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureSystolic) else {
            // This should never fail when using a defined constant.
            fatalError("*** Unable to get the bloodPressure count ***")
        }
        query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: bloodPressureSystolic,
                                  quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                  options: .discreteAverage) {
            query, statistics, error in

            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.systolicValue = statistics?.averageQuantity()
            }
        }

        healthStore!.execute(query!)
    }
    
    func calculateBloodPressureDiastolic() {
        guard let bloodPressureDiastolic = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureDiastolic) else {
            // This should never fail when using a defined constant.
            fatalError("*** Unable to get the bloodPressure count ***")
        }
        query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: bloodPressureDiastolic,
                                  quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                  options: .discreteAverage) {
            query, statistics, error in

            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.diastolicValue = statistics?.averageQuantity()
            }
        }

        healthStore!.execute(query!)
    }
    
    
}
```

How do I need to modify my code to get the correct value for healthStore.systolicValue and healthStore.diastolicValue directly when I call ContentView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full code that I use for testing and works for me,
using macos 11.4, xcode 12.5, target ios 14.5, tested on iPhone device.
Let us know if this does not work for you.

```
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit

@main
struct TestErrorApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class HealthStore: ObservableObject {
    var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
    var query: HKStatisticsQuery?
    @Published var systolicValue: HKQuantity?
    @Published var diastolicValue: HKQuantity?
    
    init() {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        }
    }

    func setUpHealthStore() {
        let typesToRead: Set = [
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureSystolic)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureDiastolic)!
        ]
        healthStore?.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: typesToRead, completion: { success, error in
            if success {
                print("--> requestAuthorization")
                self.calculateBloodPressureSystolic()
                self.calculateBloodPressureDiastolic()
            }
        })
    }
    
    func calculateBloodPressureSystolic() {
        guard let bloodPressureSystolic = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureSystolic) else {
            // This should never fail when using a defined constant.
            fatalError("*** Unable to get the bloodPressure count ***")
        }
        query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: bloodPressureSystolic,
                                  quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                  options: .discreteAverage) {
            query, statistics, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
              //  self.systolicValue = statistics?.averageQuantity()
                self.systolicValue = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit(from: ""), doubleValue: 1.2)
                print("----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic statistics: \(statistics)")
                print("----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic error: \(error)")
                print("----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic: \(self.systolicValue)")
            }
        }
        healthStore!.execute(query!)
    }
    
    func calculateBloodPressureDiastolic() {
        guard let bloodPressureDiastolic = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureDiastolic) else {
            // This should never fail when using a defined constant.
            fatalError("*** Unable to get the bloodPressure count ***")
        }
        query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: bloodPressureDiastolic,
                                  quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                  options: .discreteAverage) {
            query, statistics, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
               // self.diastolicValue = statistics?.averageQuantity()
                self.diastolicValue = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit(from: ""), doubleValue: 3.4)
                print("----> calculateBloodPressureDiastolic statistics: \(statistics)")
                print("----> calculateBloodPressureDiastolic error: \(error)")
                print("----> calculateBloodPressureDiastolic: \(self.diastolicValue)")
            }
        }
        healthStore!.execute(query!)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var healthStore = HealthStore()
    var bloodPressureStandard = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit(from: ""), doubleValue: 0.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("systolicValue: \(healthStore.systolicValue ?? bloodPressureStandard)")
            Text("diastolicValue: \(healthStore.diastolicValue ?? bloodPressureStandard)")
        }.onAppear {
            healthStore.setUpHealthStore()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I get:

--> requestAuthorization

----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic statistics: nil

----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic error: Optional(Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=11 "No data available for the specified predicate." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No data available for the specified predicate.})

----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic: Optional(1.2 ())

----> calculateBloodPressureDiastolic statistics: nil

----> calculateBloodPressureDiastolic error: Optional(Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=11 "No data available for the specified predicate." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No data available for the specified predicate.})

----> calculateBloodPressureDiastolic: Optional(3.4 ())

And the UI shows:

systolicValue: 1.2 ()

diastolicValue: 3.4 ()

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there. Your HealthStore needs to Publish the new values for
systolicValue and diastolicValue. No need for a "callUpdate()" function.

I would modify your code something as follows:

(Note once the systolicValue and diastolicValue are calculated, the model will update and the view will also automatically update itself)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var healthStore = HealthStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Platzhalter")
            Text("systolicValue: \(healthStore.systolicValue)")
            Text("diastolicValue: \(healthStore.diastolicValue)")
        }.onAppear {
            healthStore.setUpHealthStore()
        }
    }
}

class HealthStore: ObservableObject {

    var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
    var query: HKStatisticsQuery?
    
    @Published var systolicValue: HKQuantity?    //  <----
    @Published var diastolicValue: HKQuantity?   //  <----

    ...
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the data is available? To check, could you put this in the HealthStore:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
      //  self.systolicValue = statistics?.averageQuantity()
        self.systolicValue = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit(from: ""), doubleValue: 1.2)
        print("----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic statistics: \(statistics)")
        print("----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic error: \(error)")
        print("----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic: \(self.systolicValue)")
    }
```

and similarly for diastolicValue.

Comment: this is my output: ----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic statistics: Optional(<<HKStatistics: 0x60000190c420> Statistics on HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureSystolic (2021-05-05 19:17:00 +0000 - 2021-05-05 21:59:00 +0000) over sources ((null))>)
----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic error: nil
----> calculateBloodPressureSystolic: Optional(1.2 ())

Answer (score 0):

I found my error:

I declared the variables systolicValue and diastolicValue in the class HealthStore wrong. I declared them as public instead as @Published. The right code is:

```
@Published var systolicValue: HKQuantity?
@Published var diastolicValue: HKQuantity?
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: good to hear you found the cause. Please mark the answer as correct, thank you.